# Penalising DMCA requests

Tags: dmca

There are stories that Twitter is closing Twitter accounts of people filing DMCA requests against other Twitter users, including what looks like perfectly legitimate requests by photographers.

Is that legal, or is there anything in the DMCA itself that makes this illegal? (Similar to an employer who can legally fire you for any or no reason in some places, but cannot fire you for being black or legitimately complaining about harassment).

Answer (score 1):

### “People who make DMCA requests” is not a protected class under anti-discrimination law

Business do not have to deal with any particular customers if they don't want to unless the reason they aren't is due to them being a member of a protected class. SO, if they choose not to deal with you because you make DMCA requests then, subject to the contract, this is legal

### What does the [contract](https://twitter.com/en/tos) say?

> We may suspend or terminate your account or cease providing you with all or part of the Services at any time **for any or no reason**, including, but not limited to, …

Is this an “any or no reason”? Yes, it is. So, the contract can be terminated on this reason.

Comment: That wasn’t really the question. DMCA says that the company has to take down materials to keep safe, or not take down materials and it can be sued. So can they be sued for copyright infringement after retaliation?

Comment: This answers the question as asked. If you are asking do they have to honor the DMCA request even if they retaliate the answer is unequivocally yes

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong DMCA is just an extension of Copyright and since it's a "right" isn't it also a violation of the right to punish someone for enforcing that right ?

Comment: @IndianLawApplicant advocating for Nazism is your right. It’s my right not to deal with racists.

Comment: I'm not sure I get the analogy. my bad my English is broken lol. I assume copyright law doesn't extend to certain cases

Comment: @DaleM unless you are in Germany, then advocating for Nazism is Volksverhetzung and a crime.

Comment: @Trish how charmingly naive. People in Germany can and do advocate Nazi ideology and are rarely prosecuted.

Comment: Note that if you continue to lodge DMCA requests to Twitter after they ban you from their service, they're still obligated to continue processing those requests appropriately.